# How to get params from url without unescaping (golang)

Tags: go

I need to get exactly what the user has transmitted. But the method Query() unescaped the parameters before writing to map :(
Example:

```
package main

import "net/url"

func main() {
    urlString := "http://www.example.com/?url=https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%c3%a1rbara_Gordon"
    u, _ := url.Parse(urlString)
    values := u.Query()

    println(values.Get("url"))
    // expected:https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%c3%a1rbara_Gordon
    // output:  https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bárbara_Gordon
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4XRTcKKRM2s

Comment: if that URL needs to come through exactly as you see, the percent-encoded characters need to be escaped a second time. That query string has reserved characters, which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The raw, unescaped query is available in the [`URL.RawQuery`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.RawQuery) field:

```
fmt.Println(u.RawQuery)
```

This will output:

```
url=https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%c3%a1rbara_Gordon
```

Of course this is "just" a `string` and you have to parse it yourself if you only need parts of it, but there is hardly ever a need for this. If your intention is to inject the parameter value into another URL, just use [`url.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) to build it which will properly escape it.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to send value of this parameter to the database, for example. And now I have to parse this string manually, because the url.Parse will always unescape values?

Comment: @MrGodzilla: If the query was valid in the first place, you should never see that mix of characters. Quote the query string correctly, and it will parse back exactly how you want it.

Comment: @MrGodzilla It doesn't matter if you want to send the parameter into another URL or save into DB. Just save the unescaped value. They are equivalent. Why would you need the original, escaped value?

Comment: @icza Because this exact value will be searched by the user in the form as I wrote above, and I need to store it in the database in this version, despite the fact that the first and second urls are essentially the same :)

Comment: @MrGodzilla Then I would redesign your search engine. I would store the unescaped version, and if someone searches an escaped version, unescape it and then you can match with the stored, unescaped version.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, but I need to support this mix of half-excaped/unescaped values -_-

Comment: @MrGodzilla: I would highly encourage you to find a more standard solution, as any intermediary box or middleware would likely corrupt your expected value. Sending a full url in a query parameter is not some unheard of practice, and can be easily achieved in a standards compliant way.

Comment: I'll try to use url.QueryEscape() and url.QueryUnescape() methods to be sure that value doesn't contain unexpected symbols, thanks for your time, guys! :)